# Smeared labels in Qgis2threejs plugin - QGIS

Tags: qgis-plugins, labeling, 3d, qgis-2.12

I created 3d height map with qgis2threejs plugin:

[image]

My problem is that the labels of the black points is smeared as it marked.

Is there a way to present the labels in other way in the 3d image?

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please edit the title of your question to include enough information for future visitors to be able to find this thread when looking for the same problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens because your labels are created as part of the texture, which is then draped onto the surface.

For crisp and "proper" labels, do not label them in the map canvas but add the point layer to the map in qgis2threejs (it should show up in its menu) and set up one of its attributes as label.

[image]